# Minesweeper puzzle

Tags: algorithm, logic, minesweeper

I'm creating a minesweeper solver, but it's unable to solve this puzzle and nor can I figure out how to do it by hand.

Is this puzzle possible without guessing?

```
1 1 1 0
1 x 2 1
1 2 ? ?
0 1 ? ?
1 2 2 ?
x 2 ? ?
1 2 ? ?
```

There are 3 mines remaining.

Here are two possibilities I can up with:

```
1 1 1 0
1 x 2 1
1 2 x 1
0 1 1 1
1 2 2 2
x 2 x x
1 2 2 2
```

```
1 1 1 0
1 x 2 1
1 2 3 x
0 1 x 2
1 2 2 2
x 2 x 1
1 2 1 1
```

Comment: Sometimes you have to guess. This is one of the cases. Sometimes you can calculate the probability of a field containing a mine. E.g. the three ? right of the 2 look promising, the probability of them containing a mine is 40%.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without guessing. Here are two (of several) solved grids that match your example.

```
1 1 1 0
1 x 2 1
1 2 x 1
0 1 2 2
1 2 2 x
x 2 x 2
1 2 1 1

1 1 1 0
1 x 2 1
1 2 2 x
0 1 x 2
1 2 2 2
x 2 2 x
1 2 x 2
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, that there are 3 mines remaining; however I have supplied two possibilities which use 3 mines.